# Wifi driver Lenovo T420s - Where to find find driver?

Tags: wifi, lenovo

WiFi card is no go with Elementary OS. Works fine with Ubuntu so know card is ok.

Answer (score 0):

What commands typed in terminal show?

```
sudo lspci
sudo lsusb
```

You can install iwlwifi driver from the App Center.